# Specific zoom in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, zooming

I have a Gmap that has to zoom in bit by bit. To achieve this I need the Google map zoom level to be formatted like this '4.001'. I tried doing this by simply add this value as zoom level but it doesn't work.

So my question is how to achieve a Google map zoom level using multiple numbers behind the decimal. Is it even possible? If not, how do I achieve the slowly precise zooming?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want a zoom level between 4 and 5 for example 4.2 or 4.3 the only way is to use a cluster algorithm because the map is subdivide by 4. Cluster means that when the tiles are so close together that's not anymore practical to show them. There is a for example marker manager that can calculate clusters but it's not applicable to the map because it doesn't make sense to subdivide by 6 or 7 tiles.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#TileCoordinates), the zoom level corresponds to the number of tiles in which the Earth is divided:

```
zoom = 1   =>   tiles = 2^1 * 2^1 = 2 * 2 = 4
zoom = 2   =>   tiles = 2^2 * 2^2 = 4 * 4 = 16
zoom = 3   =>   tiles = 2^3 * 2^3 = 8 * 8 = 64
etc
```

Increasing the zoom level by 1 doubles the level of detail. The zoom level is an integer value. It corresponds to the discrete value of the slider control on Google maps.

Comment: So according to your explanation I should use the tile calculations to increase the zoom level with e.g. 0.01's? Do you have any examples of how to do this in php?

Comment: `var zoomLevel = 4;` zoomLevel is an integer. `map.setZoom(zoomLevel);` You cannot use e.g `4.5`. You can increase `zoomLevel` in steps of `1` e.g. from `4` to `5`.

Comment: Yes I understand, but how do I achieve something like 4.5? Through tiles??

Comment: Suppose you show your map at zoomLevel = 4. Now you want to increase a bit the zoom, say to 4.1. The message is: you cannot do that; you have to increase to 5. And if it is too detailed you need to keep the zoom at 4. There are no intermediate levels between 4 and 5.

Comment: Is there a way to increase zoom slowly? I understand it's not possible. But maybe by using tiles?? But I don't know how..

Comment: Does somebody have an idea of how to achieve a small zooming level?!?!?!

Comment: For anyone thinking about (mis)using LatLngBounds for this purpose: It won't work either.

Answer (score 2):

You can gradually CSS-zoom the map canvas from 1 to 2, perhaps also masking the surroundings with elements. 
Then in one call change the css-zoom back to 1 and decrease the maps-zoom by one. 
You will see that streets, names and lines zoom along during the zoom, which is an unwanted artefact, but it sure looks smoother than the maps' zoom.

A zoom of 4.5  could be achieved by setting the maps zoom to 4 and the CSS-zoom to 1.5.

If you don't like the lo-res result you could do the opposite: set the CSS-zoom to 0.5 and the maps-zoom to 5. Both wil have their pros and cons in terms of data-usage, pixel density, object sizes.

Answer (score 0):

In the Chrome browser, a workaround is to alternate zooming between the GMaps + and - and using "Ctrl -" and "Ctrl +" on your keyboard. This latter zoom is within Chrome.
Between the two methods you can get a more customized zoom level. One benefit from going back and forth is that you can optimize text size at the same time.